# Domain User home directory upon first login

Tags: centos, pam, sssd

I'm having some trouble setting up default files in the user home directory. The setup is a Centos 7, and I've successfully let it join the company's domain and authenticate through our AD.

I'm able to login using my domain username and password. However, I've got this error during my first login:

```
Creating home directory for boonhean.
Last login: Thu Jun 16 13:23:10 2016
Could not chdir to home directory /u/boonhean: No such file or directory
```

However, the folder did get created and I'm able to cd into it. Subsequent login has no problem as well.

Also, I've noticed that the files in my /etc/skel were not copied to the folder during the creation. It doesn't look like a permission issue because I can copy the files from there when I'm login as the user.

This is what I have in my /etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077
```

I've googled for 2 days but still can't find a solution. Can anyone spot what did I miss? I can copy the files in /etc/skel manually but its going to be difficult if I have to ask all my domain users to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? Do you see any errors with `grep -i selinux /var/log/messages`?

Comment: Yes, SELinux is enabled. Running `getenforce` shows `Enforcing`. No errors related to that in the logs as well, just `Successfully loaded SELinux policy in 742.065ms`.

Comment: Have you tried disabling it and testing? In most cases that's the culprit. Try `setenforce 0` to disable it, you can always re-enable with `setenforce 1`

Comment: Also, you can analize selinux logs by using sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log And this will show you what modules are failing, and what you should do to allow it.

Comment: Yeah! runing sealert help me see what's the problem. I've to run `grep mkhomedir /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol` follow by `semodule -i mypol.pp` to get it working. One last issue though. It works when the home root folder is on the local server. But if its on a NFS folder, I'm still getting `Invalid AVC allowed in current policy` error, but it didn't gave a solution. I've google for an hour but find no solution. Anyone knows how to solve this last problem?

Comment: And looks like this may be the answer but I can't access! https://access.redhat.com/solutions/224743